# JPQL/JPA Collect alternative

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using projection to query some data and mapping the result.

But, the resulting query extract a lot of data/columns I don't need and then the framework convert it.

That is costing a lot of performance and this "mapping" process is taking about 5 minutes.

I'm looking for alternatives and if stop using projection and use a DTO constructos, this 5 minutes becomes 200ms.

But, one of the fields I need is a primary key of a child entity.

Is there any alternative for the collect from (ORACLE) for JPQL?

Something like (the code bellow is incomplete, just to explain what I need, you can infer that, right?):

```
select new dto(id, name, collect(child.id)) from.... group by id, name
```

resulting in collection of the class

```
class dto (
   String id,
   String name,
   Collection<String> childIds
)
```

Comment: This should help: https://thorben-janssen.com/fetching-dtos-with-to-many-association/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I'm trying to keep the queries inside the JPA repository and I didn't find how to use transpormer this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' managed to solve by return the result as **Tuple** (withou collect). And then mapping using grouping (Java/Parallel Stream).

The mapping cost a lot of CPU, but It's better than it was.

With my amount of test data: It was taking 13 seconds and now 1.